# Passing BiPredicate to Stream for Comparing List of Objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

A list of Journeys can only be completed by a person if the journey timetable do not overlap. e.g. this list should return true because dates don't overlap.

```
Journey 1: "2019-09-10 21:00" --> "2019-09-10 21:10"
Journey 2: "2019-08-11 22:10" --> "2019-08-11 22:20"
Journey 3: "2019-09-10 21:30" --> "2019-09-10 22:00"
```

I have created a predicate that checks if journey times overlap. I want to use this BiPredicate in a stream. What is the correct approach to this problem?

```
public class Journey {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d H:m");
    ArrayList<Route> routes = new ArrayList<>();
    // This example should return true because there is no overlap between the routes.
    routes.add(new Route(simpleDateFormat.parse("2019-09-10 21:00"), simpleDateFormat.parse("2019-09-10 21:10")));
    routes.add(new Route(simpleDateFormat.parse("2019-08-11 22:10"), simpleDateFormat.parse("2019-08-11 22:20")));
    routes.add(new Route(simpleDateFormat.parse("2019-09-10 21:30"), simpleDateFormat.parse("2019-09-10 22:00")));

    boolean result = travelAllRoutes(routes);

    System.out.println(result);
}

public static boolean travelAllRoutes(List<Route> routes) {

    BiPredicate<Route, Route> predicate = (r1, r2) -> r1.getEndJourney().before(r2.getStartJourney());

    // boolean result = routes.stream(); // use predicate here
    return result;
}
}


class Route {
    private Date startJourney, endJourney;

    public Route(Date startJourney, Date endJourney) {
    this.startJourney = startJourney;
    this.endJourney = endJourney;
}

public Date getStartJourney() {
    return startJourney;
}

public void setStartJourney(Date startJourney) {
    this.startJourney = startJourney;
}

public Date getEndJourney() {
    return endJourney;
}

public void setEndJourney(Date endJourney) {
    this.endJourney = endJourney;
}
}
```

Comment: you want to process two elements _at a time_ from a `List<Route>` to see if two adjacent ones overlap? If so, Streams are not the tool for this, really.

Comment: there are ways to achieve that in Streams, though. For example using `IntStream.range(0, list.size()/2).mapToObj(x -> list.get(x).getEndJourney().before(x.get(x+1)))....`, but it's ugly and its _not_ a good replacement for the plain `for loop`; you could design a custom `Spliterator` - people have done that, but it's by far not easy; you could use `reduce` - but it's not short-circuiting. So no, there is no simpler way than a loop - just use that.

Comment: Why the second route is a different month and day ? error ?

Comment: Is the list of the `Route` in the input sorted by any attribute? Is the order of journeys fixed? If yes, are you ignoring a journey with a start time before the end time of another? Just to make it clear further, can you explain the processing for the input `Journey 1: "2019-09-10 21:00" --> "2019-09-10 21:10"
Journey 2: "2019-08-11 22:10" --> "2019-08-11 22:20"
Journey 3: "2019-09-10 21:30" --> "2019-09-11 22:15"`

Comment: you may think about accepting an answer now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Stream` there are not useful here, a simple `for-loop` is perfect

```
public static boolean travelAllRoutes(List<Route> routes) {
    Route lastRoute = null;
    routes.sort(Comparator.comparing(Route::getStartJourney));
    for (Route r : routes) {
        if (lastRoute == null) {
            lastRoute = r;
            continue;
        }
        if (lastRoute.getEndJourney().after(r.getStartJourney())) 
            return false;
        lastRoute = r;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Also I'd suggest to use `java.time.LocalDate` instead of the old `java.util.Date`

Comment: Additionally you must sort by the start date.